# C# Convert byte array to string, using preamble or default encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays, streamreader

Im trying to convert a byte array to a string. The byte array includes a preamble (if the used encoder had one of those), and you must specify the default encoding if no preamble is stored in the byte array.

My code looks like this

```
public static string ArrayToStringUsingPreambleOrDefaultEncoder(byte[] bytes, Encoding defaultEncoder, out Encoding usedEncoder) {
  using (var mem = new MemoryStream(bytes))
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(mem, defaultEncoder, true)) {
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    usedEncoder = reader.CurrentEncoding;
    return result;
  }
}
```

But it doesnt do the trick as I would expect. 
How do I make a StreamReader use the encoding specified by the preamble or a default encoding if no preamble is found. Do I really have to manually compare the preamble of ALL known encoders to the start of the array to find the right one?

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx): "StreamReader is designed for character input in a particular encoding". So yes, you really do need to sniff out the correct encoding from the preamble to do this. There's an example method to do this here:

http://www.personalmicrocosms.com/Pages/dotnettips.aspx?c=15&t=17

*Edit*: The above link is broken but the old page is available at Wayback Machine Internet Archive:  https://web.archive.org/web/20090203034127/http://www.personalmicrocosms.com/Pages/dotnettips.aspx?c=15&t=17*